# VB.NET ContextMenuStrip not found on form when using "for each control"

Tags: vb.net, forms, iteration, toolstripmenu

I need to do something with a ContextMenuStrip if it exists on a form.

Therefore I tried

```
    For Each c As Control In uForm.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is ContextMenuStrip Then

            Dim n As ContextMenuStrip
            n = DirectCast(c, ContextMenuStrip)

            For Each c2 As ToolStripMenuItem In n.Items
                MsgBox(c2.Text)
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

However, the ContextMenuStrip is not "there" when I iterate over the controls.
For example, when I put a button on a form, then this button is found using the above iteration.
But the ContextMenuStrip isn't.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should have to iterate thru **Components** collection as ContextMenuStrip is added to Components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This

```
For Each c As Control In uForm.components.Components

        If TypeOf c Is ContextMenuStrip Then

            Dim n As ContextMenuStrip
            n = DirectCast(c, ContextMenuStrip)

            For Each c2 As ToolStripMenuItem In n.Items
                MsgBox(c2.Text)
            Next
        End If

    Next
```

I tested Like this : This is you want?

```
   For Each c As Control In Me.components.Components

            If TypeOf c Is ContextMenuStrip Then
                MsgBox("sadfsadfsd")
            End If

        Next
```

Comment: The IDE tells me "components" is not a member of "System.Windows.Form.Forms"

Comment: @tmighty did you find the controls in same form or other forms control ?

Comment: No. I have googled around, and I found the same problem. There does not seem to be a simple solution.